# Where can I download Android SDK for 16 API level?

Tags: android

After downloading Android SDK [from here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) I could find only 18 API level in there. Why is that? I need 16 API level for my application. I'm using Ubuntu 13 if that's matter.

Comment: what IDE are you using?

Comment: @Raghunandan Intellij IDEA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SDK will only have the latest API level pre-installed. You can install any other version you need using the [SDK Manager](https://developer.android.com/tools/help/sdk-manager.html).

Comment: Thanks, but I can only see the latest API level on the SDK Manager. Is there any way to see previous versions?